# If Visual Studio crashes before you Save a project, can you recover the files?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, file-recovery

I created a project this morning, but didn't Save it.  Visual Studio just crashed, and I don't have a project folder.  Is there anywhere else the project might have been stored?  A temp folder somewhere or anywhere else I can look?  It was about 6 hours of work :/

Comment: Consider removing extensions from devenv. I know a lot of folks love resharper, e.g., but the stability hit it causes devenv is just not worth the price of entry, imo. I can't remember the last time I had devenv crash that wasn't directly attributable to a plugin or addin of some sort.

Comment: All I use is devexpress.  I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be causing issues.  I'm not even on current version.  Should be stable.

Answer (score 3):

In Win7 default folder is: `..\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Backup Files`

Comment: In Win8 it's same as this answer.  I imagine all versions.  Thanks again.